# Why is proving converses of propositions (specifically in Euclid) important?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Why does Euclid demonstrate several props by their converse or through a reduction to the absurd? In what way is proving that the converse of the prop is absurd preferable to proving constructively what the prop sets out to do.

Comment: Often it’s simply efficient. Lots of Euclids proofs come in pairs. First a constructive proof in a forward direction of a proposition, then proof by contradiction of the backward direction, using the just-demonstrated truth of the forward direction.

Comment: *Reductio ad absurdum* can be convenient because it gives you an extra starting premise to work with, and because it asks that you prove only that something *—anything!—* goes wrong. In the context of proving a converse, there's already a reasonable candidate for what could go wrong.

Comment: I wonder what you think the word "converse" means. Do you think it means "negation"?